# Python: Directory Seaching and Modifying

Tags: python, inotify, os.walk

I'm writing a script that will execute when a new file is added to a directory within the current directory. However, I'm not sure how to enter the directory and access the files. The file structure looks like this:

```
-MainDir
  -Dir1
    -File1
    -File2
    -File3
  -Dir2
    -File1
    -File2
    -File3
  -Dir3
    -File1
    -File2
    -File3
```

So, if File4 is added to Dir2, my script would execute.

I know os.walk() traverses the directory tree, but based off this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-walk-python/, I don't see a way to directly enter the directory to run my script.

I'm using inotify_simple to send a notification when a new file is created.

**Note:** I'd like this to be completely dynamic so that it would work for a directory of any given structure.

Comment: Why do you need to traverse the directory structure? Won't `inotify_simple` give you the path of the file that was added/modified directly?

Comment: This is my first time using `inotify_simple`, so I'm not sure of its complete capabilities. But, from what I can see from the docs, it doesn't look like it will return the path of the changed file. I'm hard coding the directory it's searching in, so I will need to change that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the output in the example [here](https://pypi.org/project/inotify_simple/) it shows that you get the name of the file/directory.

Comment: So if I were to create a new directory within the directory that I'm watching, then the event would look something like: `Event(..., name=u'mainDir/a/b/c.txt')` ?

Comment: Seems like it, yeah. Have you tried?

Comment: No, that's now how inotify works, it is not recursive. You need to add a watch for each directory you want to watch. When an event comes back, you can tell which directory it corresponds to by the "watch descriptor" of the event - it corresponds to the integer you got back when you originally asked inotify to watch the directory.